# Set session variable without reloading the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, post

I send a value to a `php` file with `AJAX`.

I am having this function in `jQuery`:

```
// Service select change
$container.on('change', '.bookly-js-select-service', function() {

var gekozen_behandeling = this.value;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/behandeling.php',
    data: {
      behandeling_nieuw: gekozen_behandeling
    },
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  });

});
```

After doing this it alerts done.

In my file `behandeling.php` the code is like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION["type_behandeling"] = $_POST["behandeling_nieuw"];

echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, TRUE) . '</pre>';

?>
```

After doing this and navigate to the `behandeling.php` file the `session variable` is still empty.

```
<pre>Array
(
    [bookly] => Array
        (
            [forms] => Array
                (
                    [5e1c6d8916b27] => Array
                        (
                            [defaults] => Array
                                (
                                    [service_id] => 0
                                    [staff_id] => 0
                                    [location_id] => 0
                                    [category_id] => 5
                                )

                            [last_touched] => 1578921357
                            [data] => Array
                                (
                                    [first_rendered_step] => 1
                                    [time_zone] => 
                                    [time_zone_offset] => 
                                    [date_from] => 2020-01-13
                                    [days] => 
                                    [time_from] => 09:00
                                    [time_to] => 21:00
                                    [slots] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [facebook_id] => 
                                    [full_name] => 
                                    [first_name] => 
                                    [last_name] => 
                                    [email] => 
                                    [email_confirm] => 
                                    [phone] => 
                                    [birthday] => 
                                    [additional_address] => 
                                    [country] => 
                                    [state] => 
                                    [postcode] => 
                                    [city] => 
                                    [street] => 
                                    [street_number] => 
                                    [address_iso] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [notes] => 
                                    [info_fields] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [coupon_code] => 
                                    [deposit_full] => 0
                                    [edit_cart_keys] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [repeated] => 0
                                    [repeat_data] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [cart] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [chain] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [service_id] => 
                                            [staff_ids] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [number_of_persons] => 
                                            [quantity] => 
                                            [extras] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [custom_fields] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [location_id] => 
                                            [series_unique_id] => 0
                                            [first_in_series] => 
                                            [units] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                            [booking_numbers] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [payment_id] => 
                            [payment_type] => local
                        )

                    [5e1c6dc0324c7] => Array
                        (
                            [defaults] => Array
                                (
                                    [service_id] => 0
                                    [staff_id] => 0
                                    [location_id] => 0
                                    [category_id] => 5
                                )

                            [last_touched] => 1578921411
                            [data] => Array
                                (
                                    [first_rendered_step] => 1
                                    [time_zone] => 
                                    [time_zone_offset] => 
                                    [date_from] => 2020-01-13
                                    [days] => 
                                    [time_from] => 09:00
                                    [time_to] => 21:00
                                    [slots] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [facebook_id] => 
                                    [full_name] => 
                                    [first_name] => 
                                    [last_name] => 
                                    [email] => 
                                    [email_confirm] => 
                                    [phone] => 
                                    [birthday] => 
                                    [additional_address] => 
                                    [country] => 
                                    [state] => 
                                    [postcode] => 
                                    [city] => 
                                    [street] => 
                                    [street_number] => 
                                    [address_iso] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [notes] => 
                                    [info_fields] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [coupon_code] => 
                                    [deposit_full] => 0
                                    [edit_cart_keys] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [repeated] => 0
                                    [repeat_data] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [cart] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [chain] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [service_id] => 
                                            [staff_ids] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [number_of_persons] => 
                                            [quantity] => 
                                            [extras] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [custom_fields] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [location_id] => 
                                            [series_unique_id] => 0
                                            [first_in_series] => 
                                            [units] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                            [booking_numbers] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [payment_id] => 
                            [payment_type] => local
                        )

                    [5e1c6df9da30f] => Array
                        (
                            [defaults] => Array
                                (
                                    [service_id] => 0
                                    [staff_id] => 0
                                    [location_id] => 0
                                    [category_id] => 5
                                )

                            [last_touched] => 1578921468
                            [data] => Array
                                (
                                    [first_rendered_step] => 1
                                    [time_zone] => 
                                    [time_zone_offset] => 
                                    [date_from] => 2020-01-13
                                    [days] => 
                                    [time_from] => 09:00
                                    [time_to] => 21:00
                                    [slots] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [facebook_id] => 
                                    [full_name] => 
                                    [first_name] => 
                                    [last_name] => 
                                    [email] => 
                                    [email_confirm] => 
                                    [phone] => 
                                    [birthday] => 
                                    [additional_address] => 
                                    [country] => 
                                    [state] => 
                                    [postcode] => 
                                    [city] => 
                                    [street] => 
                                    [street_number] => 
                                    [address_iso] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [notes] => 
                                    [info_fields] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [coupon_code] => 
                                    [deposit_full] => 0
                                    [edit_cart_keys] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [repeated] => 0
                                    [repeat_data] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [cart] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [chain] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [service_id] => 
                                            [staff_ids] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [number_of_persons] => 
                                            [quantity] => 
                                            [extras] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [custom_fields] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [location_id] => 
                                            [series_unique_id] => 0
                                            [first_in_series] => 
                                            [units] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                            [booking_numbers] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [payment_id] => 
                            [payment_type] => local
                        )

                    [5e1c6e0f76ddd] => Array
                        (
                            [defaults] => Array
                                (
                                    [service_id] => 0
                                    [staff_id] => 0
                                    [location_id] => 0
                                    [category_id] => 5
                                )

                            [last_touched] => 1578921490
                            [data] => Array
                                (
                                    [first_rendered_step] => 1
                                    [time_zone] => 
                                    [time_zone_offset] => 
                                    [date_from] => 2020-01-13
                                    [days] => 
                                    [time_from] => 09:00
                                    [time_to] => 21:00
                                    [slots] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [facebook_id] => 
                                    [full_name] => 
                                    [first_name] => 
                                    [last_name] => 
                                    [email] => 
                                    [email_confirm] => 
                                    [phone] => 
                                    [birthday] => 
                                    [additional_address] => 
                                    [country] => 
                                    [state] => 
                                    [postcode] => 
                                    [city] => 
                                    [street] => 
                                    [street_number] => 
                                    [address_iso] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [notes] => 
                                    [info_fields] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [coupon_code] => 
                                    [deposit_full] => 0
                                    [edit_cart_keys] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [repeated] => 0
                                    [repeat_data] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [cart] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [chain] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [service_id] => 
                                            [staff_ids] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [number_of_persons] => 
                                            [quantity] => 
                                            [extras] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [custom_fields] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [location_id] => 
                                            [series_unique_id] => 0
                                            [first_in_series] => 
                                            [units] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                            [booking_numbers] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [payment_id] => 
                            [payment_type] => local
                        )

                )

        )

    [type_behandeling] => 51
)
</pre>
```

Comment: Do you get the alert? not getting any exception?

Comment: How do you store variables to session ?

Comment: Try alert(response); and provide here

Comment: Made it a `console.log` and pasted the result beneath it. It shows the right value in `type_behandeling` but it is a booking form so in the next step I need to have the value again. How can I do that? The pages isn't refreshed when navigating to page 2

Comment: for filling `Session` or `Cookie` you had to use `return`.
you can use `return response();` and then the session fill with your giving data.

Comment: this gives me an error

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible that when you navigate to `behandeling.php` 
that you are assigning the posted variable to session as

```
$_SESSION["type_behandeling"] = $_POST["behandeling_nieuw"];
```

the posted data not found as you are visiting (http get method). Hence session is overwritten with null or empty.

Comment: Ok, I get that. But I want to re-use the session variable on the same page on clicking on something else.

Comment: you can check the variable $_POST["behandeling_nieuw"] is set or not using isset() if so change session otherwise keep as it is.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change **dataType: 'html'** to **dataType: 'JSON'**
2. Through Chrome/Firefox  Dev tools check - behandeling.php file is getting called
3. Through Chrome/Firefox  Dev tools check - form data is getting submitted to PHP File
4. Also if you access the file outside, it Recheck the $_POST Value , since the value is not set, a blank will be assigned to the session.

Check the $_POST Value

```
   if (isset($_POST["behandeling_nieuw"])) {
       $_SESSION["type_behandeling"] = $_POST["behandeling_nieuw"];

     echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, TRUE) . '</pre>';    
   } else {    
       echo "POST Value not set";

       if(isset($_SESSION['type_behandeling']) && !empty($_SESSION['type_behandeling'])) {
      echo 'Set and not empty, and no undefined index error!';
       }

       else {
           echo "Session is not set ";
       }


   }
```

Comment: Where can I check?

Comment: Check the Updated answer

Comment: I get POST Value not set

Comment: print_r($_SESSION) and check session is now available

Comment: I get POST Value not set and beneath that all the other session variables

Comment: Check the Updated answer

Comment: Says:
POST Value not setSet and not empty, and no undefined index error!

Comment: If it says - Set and not empty, and no undefined index error! That means your sessions is set and value is available Ans for 

"After doing this and navigate to the behandeling.php file the session variable is still empty."

Comment: Doesn't really understand :(

Comment: My friend your problem says when you call using ajax and set the Session variable , and then access from again by call thing the php file , the session is empty.

First try to understand why it is happening. Through Ajax call you send  "behandeling_nieuw" as a post request and the value set for the session.

But when you call the file without the Ajax call, there is no "behandeling_nieuw" value , so when script execute line by line, it assign no value to the session, so the session is empty.
.
Cond

Comment: As the solution, you assign the Session through ajax call first, then when you access the php file from outside without the ajax call first we check $_POST["behandeling_nieuw"] is available, if not we check the session is available, as per your above result, now the session is available.. hope you understand